# I would like to start ju jitsu

Tags: training, jujutsu

I wanted to know if someone aged 15-16 is good to start. I want to know what you guys think of ju jitsu. Did any of you start at 15, how are you like now.

Comment: It's a fine age to start. Just do it.

Comment: Go ahead and do it, and see if it suits you.